# How to store file creation time in linux

Tags: linux

Is there any way to store file creation time in linux? May be filesystem that supports that. I mean CREATION TIME not mtime or ctime.

Comment: What is the difference between "CREATION TIME" and ctime?

Comment: @Paul: ctime is the metadata change time.

Comment: @Paul: http://www.kavoir.com/2009/04/linux-the-differences-between-file-times-atime-accessed-time-ctime-changed-time-and-mtime-modified-time.html

Comment: Well, 99.9% of the files on my systems have never have a chmod or chown since they were created, so ctime is fine for those cases.

Comment: @Paul: ctime includes content modification. It just *also* includes chmod/chown, while mtime does not.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's lucky I've never cared about ctime because I never knew it included content modification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most (all?) Linux filesystems do not store the time when the file was created. Instead, they just store when the file was last modified, when it was last accessed, and when it last had an administrative action applied to it (e.g., changing its permissions). Of those, the best approximation to what you're looking for is usually the modification time.

Comment: On OS X there is way to get creation time of the file as well as ctime and mtime. I thought may be on linux too.

Comment: @t0ster: HFS and HFS+ support creation time. ext2/3/4 does not.

Comment: Accroding to this resource http://www.qa.com/about-qa/blogs/2010/july/creation-time-in-unix-yes---in-ext4 ext4 has such parameter as `crtime`, but it is not easy to work with (yet).

Comment: It seems the link in the last comment was wrong (or got obsoleted). The working link is http://www.qa.com/about-qa/blogs/2010/july/creation-time-in-unix-yes-in-ext4/.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that Ext4 has creation time support.
Try this debugfs:

```
debugfs -R 'stat <inode>' /dev/block_dev.

Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
ctime: 0x51872d50:df6167a0 -- Mon May  6 07:10:56 2013
atime: 0x5183b4e1:d2ad63cc -- Fri May  3 16:00:17 2013
mtime: 0x51872d50:df6167a0 -- Mon May  6 07:10:56 2013
crtime: 0x5183b4e1:d2ad63cc -- Fri May  3 16:00:17 2013
```

[Understanding EXT4 (Part 2): Timestamps](http://computer-forensics.sans.org/blog/2011/03/14/digital-forensics-understanding-ext4-part-2-timestamps#)

Answer (score 0):

On NTFS using ntfs-3g you can access the creation time via [an extended attribute](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/extended-attributes/#filetimes) (see [`attr(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/attr)).

Comment: It's an option, but don't want to have deal with NTFS on linux.

Comment: Well, your other option is HFS, and you *really* don't want to deal with HFS on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store file creation times, you can use filesystem event notification tool like [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

It has system calls that make you aware of IN_CREATE (a file creation event) or some other event, When a file creation event happens you can simply log that with current time in a file of your preference.

Comment: It's also an option, I'll take a look.